# Loop in numbers as a whole and string as singular

Tags: python

I want a function that loops through the text and print out the letters alone and the numbers alone.

I have

```
function("A10")
```

The result should be:

```
A
10
```

For:

```
    function("A1B3")
```

The result should be :

```
A
1
B
3
```

For C12H30

The result should be :

```
C
12
H
30
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to separate the characters in your string to print a certain way? Please clarify what your code's intent, and provide additional examples for expected inputs.

Comment: I have fixed it.

Comment: Looks like the question has been closed. You can iterate the string by character and use `isdigit()` to determine whether to accumulate digits before printing them, or just print the single character by itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
given_string = "A10"

for i in string:
    if i.isalpha():
        print(i)
    else:
        print(i, end='')
```

Comment: I suggestion, don't use inbuilt functions as a variable

Answer (score 1):

You could index the first value:

```
>>> name[0]
'A'
```

You could slice the rest:

```
>>> name[1:]
'10'
```

In code:

```
print(name[0])
print(name[1:])
```

Output:

```
A
10
```

Answer (score -2):

when you use "for loop"
it loop letters in the word, every letter in a single line

```
A
1
0
```